# can a continuous or differentiable function have consecutive same values over a partition [a,b]? except constant function

Tags: calculus

Can a continuous or differentiable function have consecutive same values over a partition [a,b], which means it has a graph containing a horizontal segment?

Comment: What do you mean?  There are constant functions, no?  Take $f=0$ if you want one compactly supported.

Comment: If the function is constant, the whole graph is a horizontal line.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity and to indicate your own efforts.  You should easily be able to construct a continuous piecewise linear function that does the job.  Smooth examples exist, but require more effort.  Examples can be built out of, say, $\exp\left(-\frac 1{x^2}\right)$.

Comment: exp(−1/x^2) doesn't have  consecutive same values over its domain

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, take $[a,b]=[-1,1]$.

For a continuous example, take the function
$$
f(x)=x1\{x>0\}
$$
This is the "rectified linear unit".

For a differentiable example, take:
$$
g(x)=x^31\{x>0\}
$$
The derivative of this function at $x=0$ is zero.

The answer to your question is no, if you require that the function is *real analytic* (a real analytic function for which all derivatives are zero at a point is constant everywhere).